# Producer can't resolve host after dockerize kafka

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

It will be 6 hours now that I'm trying to access to kafka with my spring producer (which I launch on local machine). When I start producer I got this issue :

```
WARN 16800 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Error connecting to node 2dd34aa10a8e:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)
java.net.UnknownHostException: 2dd34aa10a8e
```

Where 2dd34aa10a8e is the container id (kafka)

Next is my producer properties :

`spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092`

For kafka, I'm using the ubuntu/kafka image from docker hub https://hub.docker.com/r/ubuntu/kafka (same for zookeeper https://hub.docker.com/r/ubuntu/zookeeper)

I'm using docker desktop and wsl2

I'm trying to make communicate producers with kafka

Comment: Please, ensure you are running your container with the correct `network_mode` and exposing the port `correctly`. Also, Kafka depends on Zookeeper. Is it up too? I don't think Zookeeper is included in the Kafka container.

Comment: @MarcoFragDelleMonache Yes zookeeper is not included inside ubuntu/kafka image so I also build aan another container with ubuntu/zookeeper image. By default bridge is the default network driver (which is the network mode I should use ) so I should be able to connect my kafka container with my spring boot producer, isn't it ?

Comment: I hope so.. maybe you have to specify the zookeeper host to kafka

Comment: Do not use the Ubuntu/kafka image. It does not allow you to configure the necessary properties from environment variables

Comment: Also, Zookeeper is no longer required for Kafka